# Objective-c - control outlet from other class

Tags: objective-c

I just like to play with coding for a hobby, so probably a noob question;

I have a simple storyboard for MacOS with 2 views. Both have there own classes (main class and subclass). How can I control a outlet in the subclass from the main class?

**for example**

I have a button (IBAction) in the mainclass and a textfield (IBOutlet) in the subclass. I want to set the stringvalue for the textfield with a click on the button in main.

I have searched a lot last days but just don't get it. (or just need a push in the right direction)

**EDIT after JingJingTao's answer:**

I used the control-drag function to open the second window.
I tried the code JingJingTao gives, but the textfield doesn't respond to the action.
My classes look like this now:

ViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController

- (IBAction)newText:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) ViewController2 *subclass;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}

- (void)newText:(id)sender {
    self.subclass.textField.stringValue = @"button pressed";
}


@end
```

ViewController2.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 : ViewController

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;

@end
```

ViewController2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

@end
```

Comment: You cannot. Each scene is a separate nib.

Comment: you need a reference to the instance of the class that owns the outlet. but, are these 2 views both on screen at the same time? or do you really want to set some flag / state somewhere to use later...

Comment: They are both on screen at the same time

Comment: You can access all the super-classes' properties just fine. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I've attached two screenshots of what it looks like in the storyboard for the first suggestion,

1) Add a view to your ViewController, set the class at the top right to 'YourView', 'YourView' is a just an NSView, add a textfield to it and hook it up.
[image: myview1]

2) Add YourView as a property to your ViewController, i.e. `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSView *yourView;` and hook it up.
[image: myview2]

Let me know if there are any issues.

You just need to put the textfield in the public interface of your subclass, so you can access it in your main class, although it does sound like you're using inheritance and I don't think you need to but that's another topic :D.

Example:

In MainClassViewController.m

```
@interface MainClassViewController ()

@propert (nonatomic) Subclass *subclass;

@end

@implementation MainClassViewController

// I guess you already add your subclass to the main viewcontroller because they display on the same screen.

- (void)yourButtonTapMethod {
     self.subclass.textfield.text = @"Your value";
}
```

In Subclass.h

```
@interface Subclass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextfield *textfield;
```

I use Cocoa Touch instead of Cocoa, so maybe it's NSTextfield for you. Please let me know if this does not answer your question, good luck.

Comment: The textfield isnt't responding.. I have put my classes in my post above

Comment: How do you display your two viewcontrollers together at the same time? From what I can see do you initialise the two viewcontrollers in another parent class? So a couple of suggestions, 1) if possible change ViewController2 to just a view, i.e. NSView and then add it as a subview to ViewController1, this is easy to achieve with a container in the storyboard. 2) If you need two viewcontrollers, then you will need to add ViewController2 as a childviewcontroller and then also add it's view to 'ViewController' as a subview. I can provide code examples of either if necessary.

Comment: I just added a new viewcontroller in the storyboard, control-dragged from that view to a button in the mainviewcontroller. After that I assigned the .h and .m classes to it. I don't necessary need 2 viewcontrollers. So if you can give me the code examples for the first suggestion, that would be very nice!

Comment: Updated my answer with a storyboard layout for suggestion 1)

Comment: I know what you mean, but the thing is; I want to be able to place each view on a seperate screen. Maybe your second suggestion does that?

Comment: Hmm, so you want one button on screen and on another screen you want the textfield, so when you user presses the button, it goes to the second screen and the textfield has a value? If that's the case, I've misunderstood :p, just pass the string to the second viewcontroller when you push it, that works?